# Going to trial on civil conspiracy claim when underlying tort claim is settled?

Tags: tort, settlement, civil

If a fraud claim for example is settled against a certain party defendant, can a dependent civil conspiracy claim still stand against another defendant that did not commit the tort but conspired to do so? Or is it subject to dismissal as a matter of law after the underlying tort is settled?

Answer (score 1):

> is it subject to dismissal as a matter of law after the underlying tort is settled?

Yes, it would be dismissed. [*Beck v. Prupis*, 529 U.S. 494(2002)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/20001023529us49411004) cites various authorities in the sense that

> [s]ince liability for civil conspiracy depends on performance of some
>   underlying tortious act, the conspiracy is not independently
>   actionable; rather, it is a means for establishing vicarious liability
>   for the underlying tort.